# Messaging service between Android devices

Tags: java, android

I want to develop an application where multiple android devices share the same application if (let's say) one device writes a message and stores it, it get's updated on all the other devices sharing the application. The details of what the app does doesn't matter, I only want to know how this would be implemented.

My idea would be for a socket from each device connected to a mutual server and each device constantly updating and waiting. Would this be the correct approach?

Thanks! Any other information would be great :D

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest (the constant polling) will drain the battery unnecessarily. You'd want to have a connection that's mostly idle, where the server notifies the clients (all but the primary actor) that a piece of information changed.

This is also known as push notifications because the servers push data down to the clients rather than the clients pulling it continuously.

In practice, this is pretty hard to implement, from having to deal with switchover between networks, through latencies, to battery impact and performance.

Consider using [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) or other 3-rd party services to spare yourself the wheel reinvention cycle.

Comment: Is GCM something that let's say SnapChat would use?

Comment: For the servers-to-device channel? Sure, I don't see why they wouldn't. There are some volume limitations which might be below Snapchat's numbers but for a just-starting app, no reason not to use it.